# Как просчитать смещение переменной в классе(ASM)

Tags: c++, ассемблер, reverse-engineering

Имеется класс конструктор, в котором объявлены переменные :

```
HANDLE          Handle;
INT             Size;
INT             Pos;
INT             BufferBase;
INT             BufferCount;
BYTE            Buffer[1024];
```

в диассмеблере это выглядит следующим образом:

```
.text:110016A0 var_10          = dword ptr -10h
.text:110016A0 var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
.text:110016A0 var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:110016A0 arg_0           = dword ptr  8
.text:110016A0 arg_4           = dword ptr  0Ch
.text:110016A0 arg_8           = dword ptr  10h
```

Каким образом можно получить оффсет этих переменных используя ASM.

Можно ли использовать оператор lea ?

```
int offset;
    __asm
{   
            lea     eax, [ecx + var_10] //or ecx+10 ? //Buffer
            mov     dword ptr[offset], eax
}
```

Comment: Ваш вопрос с `lea` как-то вносит непонятки в топик. Вы хотите понять, будет ли влиять на производительность использование подобных макро-констант, типа `var_10` или Вы хотите узнать, как автоматически получить смещения для всех полей какого-либо класса `c++`? Если первое, то - нет, ни как не будет влиять. Если второе - указывайте конкретный компилятор в метках к вопросу, т.к. в общем случае этот вопрос имеет решение только для конкретных реализаций `RTTI`.

Comment: Я не могу придумать условий, когда стоит мешать С++ с ассемблером. Гораздо продуктивнее как следует настроить компилятор, нежели городить трудноподдерживаемый кошмар, который неизвестно когда и как сломается.

Comment: Приведенные вами параметры стека явно покзывают, что функция принимает минимум три аргумента, а массива там вообще не видно. Что-то вы не то в соответствие переменным ставите...

Comment: Что то я не понял, как вы получили такую картину. Если это класс, то у каждого его экземпляра своя область памяти, выделяемая либо из стека, для локальных объектов, либо динамически во время выполнения с помощью malloc(new). В тексте asm кода времени компиляции их не будет. Если вы видите их в тексте - значит они глобальные или статические. А вот эти названия `var...` каждый компилятор сделает по своему и при небольших изменениях в программе может вообще их переименовать. А если вам эти имена вообще придумал диассемблер, то по именам вы уж точно к ним не обратитесь.

Comment: @mega Я забыл указать что - доступа к C++ Сурсам нету, и все манипуляции происходят хуком(т.е подменой функции по адресу класса и оттуда уже работой)

Comment: @LighFusion, если я Вас правильно понял, Вы хотите получить доступ к классу чужой программы. Думаю, Вы просто неправильно поняли подсказки дизассемблера. К примеру `IDA` делает такие метки, но ее `var_xxx` - основаны либо на предположениях ее анализатора, либо на логике, которая ведет на конкретные вызовы API: все эти вызовы документированы, поэтому в таком asm'е можно понять, какими структурами пользовался программист. Причем речи о пользовательских классах тут быть не может, а сами метки делаются исключительно для реверс-инженера (human use).

Comment: @mega да так и есть , я хочу понять как можно вычислить оффсет переменных в чужой программе, в ручную ?

Comment: "вручную?" -- увы, но скорее всего - да. Шансов на то, что произвольная программа собрана с какой-то `RTTI` очень мало. Но Вы можете попробовать это выяснить. Начните с компилятора, например, с помощью `PEid`. А дальше - ищите документацию по `RTTI` для этого компилятора.

Comment: @mega Возможно программа была скомпилирована в Visual studio 2005, т.е это скорее всего ! А документацию к конкретному вычислению переменной( в ручную) вы не могли бы скинуть ? либо описать этот процесс ?

Comment: @LighFusion По моему вы подходите к вопросу не с той стороны. Вот у нас есть Handle, он наверняка используется для передачи его в какие то WinAPI. Найдите в коде точки вызова этого апи, И посмотрите откуда и по каким указателям берутся данные для передачи.

Comment: @Mike да я могу найти откуда он вызывает но это мне ничего не даст, поскольку оттуда передается только Filename,Handle,Size, и флаги помоему. А сама работа с теми переменными которые я указал - происходит конкретно в функции класса, и эти переменные там участвуют, я хочу воссоздать эту функцию в своем хуке, но для этого я должен понять как в ручную вычислять офсет для каждой переменной, а этого в гугле -толквого как то не смог нарыть - к сожалению !

Comment: @LighFusion: Используя *какой* ASM??? Ситаксис разнообразных "рефлективных" фич и их наличие/отсутствие зависит от реализации транслятора ассемблера. Никакого стандарта тут нет.

Comment: @LighFusion Так он вызывает АПИ из функций этого класса, который вы исследуете ? так в любом случае при вызове функции члена класса ей в стеке будет передан указатель на this, от этого указателя функция должна отсчитать некое смещение, что бы по нему получить тот самый handle для передачи в winapi. вы находите точку передачи и просто _видите_ в коде примененное смещение относительно this для доступа к переменной.

Comment: @AnT Да обычный ASM в C++, пример  `__asm
 {
  mov eax, [ecx + 80]
   mov  dword ptr[Handle], eax
 } ` 80 Это оффсет переменной Handle, его я получил - добавив printF(offsetof(classname,Handle) в своей тестовой программе, но для основной программы мне нужно понять как его вычислить в ручную ? многие просто говорят что есть этот способ а описать его или дать ссылку не могут ) ?

Comment: @Mike а как это будет выглядеть на примере - можно взглянуть ? Ибо примерно представить я могу, но на практике могу наверное делать совсем другое нежели то что вы описали.

Comment: @LighFusion: Нет никакого "обычного ASM в C++". У каждого компилятора С++ совершенно различный синтаксис и возможности asm. Даже близко не похожи.

Comment: @AnT Это к сожалению не как не поможет мне в решении моей задачи, если даже я и буду знать какой там именно синтаксис, я всеравно не знаю как по нему работать чтобы определить оффсет, мне бы на материал какой нибудь взглянуть - где именно идет работа с ассемблерным кодом, и где в итоге получается вычислить это самое смешение.

Comment: @LighFusion Вы бы полный дизассемблерный текст какой нибудь функции того класса обращающейся к WinAPI привели. А потом бы скопилили свою функцию которая будет вызывать тот же winapi и передавать какие то параметры, так что бы эти параметры можно было увидеть в ассемблерном коде вашей функции. После чего можно будет просто сравнить вызовы и понять откуда чужая функция достала данные для вызова

Comment: @Mike: Смещения полей в классе являются константами времени компиляции. Они не будут ниоткуда доставаться. Они будут явно вписаны прямо в ассемблерный код. Поэтому рассматривание дизассемблированного кода тут ничем не поможет.

Comment: @AnT правильно, будут вписаны в код исследуемой функции и их там будет явно видно. собственно вот эти константы и надо получить ТС

Comment: @Mike вы имейте ввиду взять что-то отсюда(Это функция которую мне  нужно подменить) ? http://pastebin.com/GRuJWSm6 , и передать в ASM, а после в переменную ?  http://pastebin.com/5NLDV3S1 псевдокод !

Comment: @Mike: Да, но вся идея ТС-освского вопорса как раз и сводится к тому, чтобы получить эти константы неявно, не вписывая конкретные значения в код. Чтобы если завтра определение класса поменяется, то не надо было рыскать по коду и руками исправлять смещения. Т.е. ТС ищет ассемблерный аналог стандартного сишного `offsetof`.

Comment: @AnT Я честно сказать не хочу это усложнять, если можно в ручную не явно это выяснить, я бы хотел просто узнать - наглядно как это производиться ? имею ввиду расчет чего к чему, внутри дизасм кода чтобы получить смешение.

Comment: @LighFusion Как думаете, приведенная вами функция может быть констрактором класса ? Уж больно много она переменных класса ставит в какие то явно дефолтные значения 0 и 1 в несколько полей распихивает.

Comment: @Mike Так эта функция внутри класса конструктора, вот примерный ее код - но в той программе для которой я подменяю - он подругому реализован. http://pastebin.com/hJ0f0daf

Comment: @LighFusion Короче, по второй ссылке данной вами отлично все читается. За вас декомпилятор много работы сделал. Видите там строчки v6=this, v18=this. v18 нас не особо интересует, а вот v6 очень интересна, например в (v6 +14) лежит какое то очень полезное значение. оно получается после вызова GetFileSize и еще какой то функции и далее используется при вызове еще нескольких функций. Вы когда хук будете вешать у вас на входе будут те параметры которые вы видите в этом коде. Первым параметром будет указатель this и как раз прибавляя к нему 14 можно будет получить ту важную переменную

Comment: @LighFusion А вот что это за переменные что бы узнать, можно попробовать найти те функции что он вызывает и посмотреть что с этими параметрами дальше переходит. В идеале судьбу переменных надо отследить до вызовов известных WinAPI, там вам даже декомпилятор подскажет что это такое

Comment: @Mike - спасибо вам за информацию - сейчас попробую!

Comment: @LighFusion Судя по третьему данному вами коду в this+14 содержится адрес такого же объекта как в вашем коде создает `new(TEXT("WindowsFileReader"))FArchiveFileReader(Handle,Error,GetFileSize(Handle,NULL));`

Comment: @LighFusion И как раз логично, что этот this+14 передается первым параметром в кучу других функций. Это функции того класса и их первый переметр это как  раз их this

Comment: @LighFusion Забыл уточнить, что там this+14 употребляется в виде DWORD *, т.е. смещение в байтах 14*4, но вы наверняка то же будете обращаться к нему как DWORD *, так что будете 14 использовать. За ним 4 байта занимает некий int, в который кладут число, видимо прочитанное из файла и которое в том файле лежит в явном виде, потому как  к нему применяют atoi

Comment: @Mike Спасибо вам огромное что так подробно это описали! , а что такое atoi ?

Comment: @LighFusion atoi стандартная функция C которая из строки из цифр, например "121" получает собственно число 121 в машинном виде, что бы положить его в int. 121 я не просто так привел, там в коде можете увидеть они как раз это число проверяют и если оно 121 то что то делают, а если 111 то делают что то другое. Ну вот как то так надо анализировать что там декомпилятор дал и пытаться догадаться что это может быть. Мне сложно, я под виндой ничего никогда не делал и всех этих классов не знаю, вам думаю ближе :)

Comment: @LighFusion Да, там в классах по указателю который в this+0 таблица виртуальных функций. так что когда видите ` (*(void (__stdcall **)(int))(**((_DWORD **)v6 + 14) + 60))(v5);` не пугайтесь, это всего лишь вызывается некая виртуальная функция этого класса (адрес объекта которого как раз в v6+14) и ей передается 1 параметр.

Comment: @Mike а не подскажите что тогда такое,  *((_BYTE *)v6 + 68) = -84; -84 ? Это результат ожидаемой работы или ссылка ?

Comment: @LighFusion `_BYTE` мы рассматриваем this как указатель на массив char, и по смещению 68 кладем явно 1 байт со значением -84. Т.е. в вашем объекте this по абсолютному (в байтах) смещению 68 лежит некий char[1] который в данном случае равен -84, что то же самое что 0xAC или, если это unsigned char = 172

Comment: @Mike , т.е  обратившись через `__asm
 {
          mov eax, [ecx + 68]
   mov  dword ptr[charArr], eax
 }` в моем сharArr, будет попадать тоже что и в оригинале ?

Comment: @LighFusion dowrd это 4 байта, а вам нужен 1, соответственно что то типа mov al,[ecx+68]; mov byte ptr[charArr], al а вообще я бы рекомендовал как нибудь из asm хука вызвать свою сишную функцию которой попроще все это делать будет

Comment: @Mike А каким образом можно узнать размер массива, или правильно обратиться к нему ? поскольку я так понял я обращаюсь только к 1 элементу. У меня хук - http://pastebin.com/RWmjvdbH так устроен.

Comment: @LighFusion Вообще пример некорректен, в this+68 не массив, а просто 1 байт, просто `char`, а не `char *`, я бы сказал, что видимо это некий флаг или еще что то такое. И у вас с такими асм вставками есть проблема, вы уверены, что ecx все еще равен this в том месте где вы делаете эту вставку ? Компилятор может использовать регистры как ему хочется. Первая и единственная ваша asm вставка и вообще первым действием в хуке должна быть `void *T; __asm { mov T,ecx };` скомпилить свой код, посмотреть его в asm виде и убедится, что с ecx еще ничего не сделали не момент вашей вставки

Comment: @Mike А каким образом можно обратиться на функцию - которая находиться внутри ? Т.е к примеру есть ` return new(TEXT("WindowsFileReader"))FArchiveFileReader(Handle,Error,GetFileSize(Handle,NULL));` - Handle,Error,FileSize, я воссоздал, но вот как передать обратно ? Т.е как указать через ASM Эту функцию чтобы и потом передать ?

Comment: @LighFusion Так сложно слишком, смотри что я выше написал, тебе надо сам ecx сохранять в нормальную переменную и дальше с ней работать уже на C коде. И сейчас я поставил visual studio и обнаружил что копилятор умудряется портить ecx еще в самом начале функции. Включи assembler output и посмотри код который генерит твой компилятор. лично у меня почти в самом начале в преамбуле он делает mov ecx,52 даже его не сохраняя перед этим :(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32552/discussion-between-mike-and-lighfusion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если рассматривать С++, то можно использовать `offsetof()`:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void printOffsets()
    {
        std::cout << offsetof(MyClass, Handle) << std::endl;
        std::cout << offsetof(MyClass, Size) << std::endl;
        std::cout << offsetof(MyClass, Pos) << std::endl;
        std::cout << offsetof(MyClass, BufferBase) << std::endl;
        std::cout << offsetof(MyClass, BufferCount) << std::endl;
        std::cout << offsetof(MyClass, Buffer) << std::endl;
    }

private:
    HANDLE          Handle;
    INT             Size;
    INT             Pos;
    INT             BufferBase;
    INT             BufferCount;
    BYTE            Buffer[1024];
};
```

Это в С++. Думаю, что если вам всё же по некоторым причинам нужно использовать `asm`, то, думаю, что применить это вам не составить труда, и, пожалуйста, ставьте в следующий раз соответствующий тег.

Comment: Про этот метод я знаю, но мне его нужно применить к дизассемблированным сурсам, если такое вообще возможно!

Comment: Вы вполне можете вызвать `offsetof` из асма, элементарным `call`, в крайнем случае просто написать простейшую програму, дизассемблировать, посмотреть как конкретно она вызывается и применить у себя.

Comment: @Yurly , так в том то и дело что я не очень понимаю как применить ofseetof к переменной, вот к примеру у меня дизассемблер перевел переменную Handle в dword ptr -10h , как указать на нее offsetof ? Не могли бы мне привести  пример ?

Comment: @LighFusion конкретно сейчас посмотреть не могу, да и желание копаться в асме нет. а в целом параметры вызова функций помещаются в стек (esp либо rsp), это вы так же можете посмотреть в дизассемблированном варианте.

Comment: спасибо - ивправду есть такое вот ` sub     esp, 1Ch` - нужно сделать call ofsetoff на это значение ? Или не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку где подобное проделывается ?

Comment: хм, поковырялся немного, `offsetof` - это просто дефайн, при компиляции если писать что-то вроде `x = offsetof(...);`, то это преобразуется просто в один `mov` без всяких вызовов, т. е. если вам нужен оффсет члена класса, то его можно скопировать если такой же где-то встречается либо вычислить неявными способами, иначе невозможно.

Comment: а можно чуть подробнее про неявный способ ?

Comment: статейку или пример возможно увидеть ?

Comment: @Yuriy Orlov, ответ-то исправьте, не все читают комментарии.

Comment: offsetof - это макрос. Компилятор заинлайнит константу.

Answer (score 0):

> @mega Возможно программа была скомпилирована в Visual studio 2005, т.е это скорее всего ! А документацию к конкретному вычислению переменной( в ручную) вы не могли бы скинуть ? либо описать этот процесс ?

Начать можно отсюда: http://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/23920.all Хотя я по прежнему сомневаюсь, что там есть полезная информация о пользовательских полях. Сами полиморфные классы могут быть дополнены `RTTI`, эта информация может что-то рассказать о структуре объекта, его иерархии (можно определить предков, получить на них смещения). Но вот насчет смещения конкретных полей этих классов - не лазил так глубоко.

Гораздо больше шансов получить данные по классу, если у Вас есть `pdb-файл`, соответствующий Вашей программе. Вот с такой базой MS дает [очень хороший API по исследованию программ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x93ctkx8.aspx).

Отчасти, аналогичную информацию можно получить и без дополнительных библиотек, `pdb` и `OLE` - из объектных файлов `COFF`, а иногда даже из самого `PE`, но это уже более специфичный и маловероятный путь. `DIA-SDK` здесь выигрывает в плане универсальности, то есть он может сам проверить наличие всех возможных источников отладочной информации к заданному `exe` и предоставить к ним унифицированный доступ.

Comment: К сожалению pdb, coff И прочих файлов к ней нету, и PE Думаю тоже мало что даст, поскольку программа имеет специфичную защиту, и в отладчике не показывает имена функций и прочего. Конкретно по вашей ссылке я не увидел ничего про использование отладчика+asm для выяснения значения - офсета переменных в классе. По сути именно это мне нужно - хороший мануал - который бы описывал как в ручную это все разузнать, именно с примером от начала - до получившегося результата ? Такое возможно найти ?

Comment: Увы, мануалов не встречал. По первой ссылке рассказывают что такое `RTTI` и где ее искать. Полноценную структуру `RTTI` я тоже не встречал в документации. Но это было лет 10 назад, сейчас может быть все иначе.